# Why does defining RUSTFLAGS cause rustflags in .cargo/config to be ignored?

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo

I have this as my ./cargo/config:

```toml
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc"
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"]
```

I have defined RUSTFLAGS in build.sh like so:

```sh
export RUSTFLAGS='--cfg chip_type="es"'
```

When I do:

```
cargo build --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

I find that the `"-C", "target-feature=+crt-static"` is not included. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from [Cargo Configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildrustflags) on `build.rustflags`:

> There are three mutually exclusive sources of extra flags. They are checked in order, with the first one being used:
>
> 1. `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable.
> 2. All matching `target.<triple>.rustflags` and `target.<cfg>.rustflags` config entries joined together.
> 3. `build.rustflags` config value.

So this new `build.sh` code solves my problem:

```sh
RUSTFLAGS='--cfg chip_type="es" '$RUSTFLAGS
RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static '$RUSTFLAGS
export RUSTFLAGS
```